# How to mimic Eloquent model conversions to json when return to requests?

Tags: laravel

I'm creating a custom class like this :

```
<?php namespace App\Models\NonDbModels;

class BaseNonDbModel
{
    public function __construct($values)
    {
        foreach ($values as $key => $value)
        {
            if (property_exists($this, $key)) {
                $this->$key = $value;
            }
        }
    }

    public function toArray()
    {
        return get_object_vars($this);
    }

    public function toJson()
    {
        return json_encode($this->toArray());
    }

    public function __toString() : string
    {
        return $this->toJson();
    }
}
```

In controller, i will return the object to a request like this

```
$object = new BaseNonDbModel();
return $object;
```

it will correctly return a json string, but return type will be HTML. But if it's an Eloquent model, response type will be application/json. How do I mimic that behaviour of an Eloquent model, I tried reading Eloquent code but seems like they are not doing anything different, is it in Laravel core to recognize Eloquent and change response type to application/json ?

I know i can return

```
return Response::json($object)
```

or maybe create a middleware forcing application/json type for all requests, but that's not what I'm after, I prefer just return $object as comfortably as Eloquent models.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

You can create a GeneralResponse trait

```
<?php

namespace App\Traits;

use Illuminate\Http\JsonResponse;
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Response;


trait GeneralResponse
{
    public function response(
        $status = true,
        $message = null,
        $data = [],
        $code = Response::HTTP_OK,
        $display = false,
        $code2 = null
    ): JsonResponse {
        $response = [
            'status'  => $status,
            'display' => $display,
        ];

        if($message) {
            $response['message'] = $message;
        }
        if($code2) {
            $response['code'] = $code2;
        }
        if($data) {
            $response['data'] = $data;
        }
        return response()->json($response, $code);
    }


}
```

In controller where you have to return response use it like:

```
use GeneralResponse;

return $this->response(true, 'message', null, Response::HTTP_OK, true);
```

Let me know if you need any more clarification.

Comment: Thanks for the insights. However, this is not what I'm after too. I want a solution where the controller side doesnt have to do anything, just return the object, exactly how returning an Eloquent object works. I suspect it's some thing we can do with the model object itself

Comment: Yes but in that case if Laravel make any updates in new version related to eloquent then may be your application will stop working.
So better way is to go with some trait or interface

Comment: I highly doubt it. If we can mimic exactly what Laravel does with Eloquent object for this certain matter, unless Laravel is changing Eloquent, it wont break